# Parameter Expansion With Python

Tags: python, bash, expansion

I am trying to write a script takes a word and prints the first three characters, the last 3 characters, and whatever lies in the middle in dots:

abracabra

abr...bra

I made it work,

```
word = input("What's the word ?")
first = str(word[0:3])
last = str(word[-3:])
middle = int(len(word)-6)
midDOTS = "." * (middle)
print((first)+(midDOTS)+(last))
```

but I would like to do it on one line, like I can do in bash, for example this returns a list of network interfaces:

```
INTFACES=$(/sbin/ifconfig -a | sed 's/[ \t].*//;/^\(lo\|\)$/d')
```

How do I do this with python? I tried this, but it did not work:

```
word = input("What's the word ?")
midDOTS = "." * (int(len(word)-6))
print(str(word[0:3])+(midDOTS)+ str(word[-3:]))
```

What is the correct syntax?

**Edit**

Thanks to everyone for helping me not only get this correct, but understand it as well. Here is what I ended up going with...

```
def print_dotted_word():
    word = str(input("What's the word ?"))
    if len(word)<7:
        raise ValueError("Needs to be at least 7 letters.")
    print(word[:3] + '.'*(len(word)-6) + word[-3:])

while True:
    try:
        print_dotted_word()
        break
    except ValueError:("Needs to be at least 7 letters.")
```

Comment: You have a syntax error there, `midDOTS = "." * (int(len(word)` is supposed to be `midDOTS = "." * (int(len(word)-6))`

Comment: Yes, I just fixed it, thanks. But the script still does not run.

Comment: Oh wait -- You are right! It does work now! Thank you very much.

Comment: no problem, glad to help.

Comment: What if the word is 'hello'? helllo? Wouldn't you want any word greater than six characters to follow your rule?

Comment: Yeah, that could be an issue, good call. Maybe I should add a try statement and mandate that the word is at least 7 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
word = input("What's the word ?")
if len(word)<7:
    raise ValueError("Please enter a word greater than 6 characters")
print(word[:3] + '.'*(len(word)-6) + word[-3:])
```

Here, we will raise a `ValueError` exception if the `word` entered is less than 7 characters.

We can check this in Python shell by enclosing this code in a function `print_dotted_word()`.

**Python 2.7:**

```
In [1]: def print_dotted_word():
            word = raw_input("What's the word ? \n") # use raw_input
            if len(word)<7: # check for word length
                raise ValueError("Please enter a word greater than 6 characters") # raise exception
            print word[:3] + '.'*(len(word)-6) + word[-3:] # print desired response

In [2]: print_dotted_word()
What's the word ? 
helloworld
hel....rld

In [3]: print_dotted_word()
What's the word ? 
hello
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 print_dotted_word()
      2     word = raw_input("What's the word ? \n")
      3     if len(word)<7:
----> 4         raise ValueError("Please enter a word greater than 6 characters")
      5     print word[:3] + '.'*(len(word)-6) + word[-3:]

ValueError: Please enter a word greater than 6 characters
```

**Python 3.4:**

```
In [1]: def print_dotted_word():
            word = input("What's the word ? \n") # use input here
            if len(word)<7: # check for word length
                raise ValueError("Please enter a word greater than 6 characters") # raise exception 
            print(word[:3] + '.'*(len(word)-6) + word[-3:]) # print desired response

In [2]: print_dotted_word()
What's the word ? 
helloworld
hel....rld

In [3]: print_dotted_word()
What's the word ? 
hello
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 print_dotted_word()
      2     word = input("What's the word ? \n")
      3     if len(word)<7:
----> 4         raise ValueError("Please enter a word greater than 6 characters")
      5     print(word[:3] + '.'*(len(word)-6) + word[-3:])
      6 
ValueError: Please enter a word greater than 6 characters
```

Comment: Okay, I see where you are going with this, but the program still crashes. I am very new to python, but familiar with bash. I see this is an if statement, shouldn't there be an else to catch the error? Everything is good except I am getting a traceback with my error message. How do I deal with that?

Comment: The program raises a `ValueError` exception if input string is less than 7 characters. Raising an exception causes the program execution to stop if it is not caught. If you want the program to not crash, you need to add a `try/except` as you did above.  And no, there should be not be an `else` as  exception should be raised only in case of `if`. Also, we use `try/except` to catch exceptions in Python and not an `else` statement.